# Trying to export and use login info using easygui

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

I am trying to create a login screen, which does the following
- Create a user.
- Safely store a password, never in texform. Should be stored as Hash.
- modify a user(password)
- Reset password
- Delete user info
So far I am stuck and struggeling with getting the input stored in a simple text file.
I am not sure how to implement this in my code.
I have the following code:

```
import easygui

pww=open("password.txt", "w")
unw=open("username.txt", "w")
usr=open("username.txt", "r")
pwr=open("password.txt", "r")

msg = "Heb je inloggegevens?"
title = "Inloggen"
choices = ["Ja, login", "Nee, registreer"]
choice = easygui.choicebox(msg, title, choices)

if choice[0]:
    msg = "Login met je inloggegevens"
    title = "Inloggen"
    fieldnames = ["Gebruikersnaam"]
    fieldvalues = []
    fieldvaules = easygui.multenterbox(msg, title, fieldnames)
    easygui.passwordbox(msg='Voer je wachtwoord in', title='Wachtwoord', default='')

if choice[1]:
    msg = "Maak een gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord aan"
    titel = "Registeren"
    fieldNames = ["Gebruikersnaam", "Wachtwoord"]
    fieldValues = []
    fieldVaules = easygui.multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)


#if choices==choces[1]:


#easygui.multpasswordbox(msg="



#    easygui.ynbox("Nog geen account? Klik dan op registeren", "Inloggen", ("Inloggen", "Registreren"))
#    multpasswordbox(msg="Inloggen", title="Login", fields=(
#    file.write(
```

Sorry for the dutch its required to be in it for me to understand a bit of what I am doing.
If anyone can assist in this matter I would kindly accept any help regarding my question.

please note that the code works until

```
(if choice[0]:
    msg = "Login met je inloggegevens"
    title = "Inloggen"
    fieldnames = ["Gebruikersnaam"]
    fieldvalues = []
    fieldvaules = easygui.multenterbox(msg, title, fieldnames)
    easygui.passwordbox(msg='Voer je wachtwoord in', title='Wachtwoord', default='')
    )
```

but it does not store or get the info from anywhere.

Comment: Tags should identify things likely to be directly involved in the question.  Neither IDLE nor requests module seem to qualify.  To move on, I suggest adding 'print(choice)' after the 'choice = ...' statement.  I suspect that it is not what you think and that 'choice[0 (or 1]' is not the expression you want.